# How to provide configuration for a js bundled app?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, architecture, web-deployment

When I build a backend app, I can build a package only once, sign it and deploy the same package on many different environments: production, uat, dev etc. It will read db url, passwords and all other config options from environment or command line.

how it should be done with js app (e.g react or angular)? my frontend should use different backend for production and uat. what's the industry standard for doing this? building package multiple times, once for each environment? or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

A browser cannot access environmental variables, even the environment URLs are different. Of course, you can place these variables somewhere in load balancer layer and based on incoming URL return JS with specific configurations, but this is not a common solution.

I suggest making build per environment. The easiest way is to configure jobs like:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
  "build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",
  "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build",
}
```